# Android Bluetooth Printing

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am writing an application which sends data to bluetooth printer. Can anyone help me ? how can I use android Bluetooth Stack for printing? or is there any external api or sdk to use?

Here is my code for searching bluetooth...

```
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver,
        new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                    + device.getAddress());
            btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

and here is my code for sending data to printer..

```
BluetoothDevice mDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:15:FF:F2:56:A4");
Method m = mDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
        new Class[] { int.class });
mBTsocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mDevice, 1);
System.out.println("Connecting.....");
mBTsocket.connect();
System.out.println("Connected");
OutputStream os = mBTsocket.getOutputStream();
os.flush();
os.write(Receipt.getBytes());
// mBTsocket.close();
```

When I write socket.close() , data is not getting print to printer as socket connection getting closed before printing data..and if I didn't write socket.close() then data is getting printed only once.. I would not be able to print data second time until I restart bluetooth of my phone.

can any one have solution for it??? or is there any other way to get rid of this printing??

Comment: I want to send simple text from my android device to my bluetooth supported thermal printer.. but i m littelbit confused about how to send data to that bluetooth printer,

Comment: @NiravBhandari : I am stuck with a similar problem. My application pretty much does the same thing. It would you be great if I could get in touch with you for some help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution of my problem...

if i want to print data more than one time then you dont need to create new Socket Connection with the device... instead call outputstream.write(bytes) method.

and in the end if you want to disconnect device then call mBTScoket.close() method to disconnect device.

Comment: Thats great, please don't mark my answer as accepted. Mark your answer. coz you solved it by your own effort

Comment: which permission did you use in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use printooth library for any printer, printooth is simple and well documented,
https://github.com/mazenrashed/Printooth

```
var printables = ArrayList<Printable>()
var printable = Printable.PrintableBuilder()  
    .setText("Hello World") //The text you want to print
    .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.ALLIGMENT_CENTER)
    .setEmphasizedMode(DefaultPrinter.EMPHASISED_MODE_BOLD) //Bold or normal  
    .setFontSize(DefaultPrinter.FONT_SIZE_NORMAL)
    .setUnderlined(DefaultPrinter.UNDELINED_MODE_ON) // Underline on/off
    .setCharacterCode(DefaultPrinter.CHARACTER_CODE_USA_CP437) // Character code to support languages
    .setLineSpacing(DefaultPrinter.LINE_SPACING_60)
    .setNewLinesAfter(1) // To provide n lines after sentence
    .build()
printables.add(printable)
BluetoothPrinter.printer().print(printables)
```

Comment: can we connect and print a4 paper?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made connection to the devices and paired it.

So for printing, printer wants the byte. SO I have createed a mothod.

Simply call this method and pass the String inside it to get printed.

**`String str = new String("This is the text sending to the printer");`**

```
private void printData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String newline = "\n";
    try {
        out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
        Log.i("Log", "One line printed");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothDemo.this, "catch 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Log", "unable to write ");
        flagCheck = false;
    }
    try {
        out.write(newline.getBytes(),0,newline.getBytes().length);
    } catch (IOException e) {        
        Log.i("Log", "Unable to write the new line::");
        e.printStackTrace();
        flagCheck = false;
    }
    flagCheck = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer man...actually i was unable to connect to printer. I have tried as per android developer website mentioned...can you pls help me how can i connect my android device to printer?

Comment: Please answer for the questions i am asking here, so that I can help you clearly. Have you searched for the devices using bluetooth?? Are you getting the list of bluetooth devices?? Have you did pairing with the two bluetooth devices??

Comment: I have edited question with code of search bluetooth and send data to bluetooth as you mentioned...pls review it

Comment: i got the solution...i have answered it..thanks for your kind support