# IOException after first print

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth

I have an android application sending data to bluetooth printer. everything is ok for first print, but after first print getting error

Error :

```
IOException : read failed socket might closed or timeout read
```

This is my printer code:

```
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter
                    .getDefaultAdapter();

            BluetoothDevice secilenYazici = mBluetoothAdapter
                    .getRemoteDevice(sharedPrefs.getString("PRINTER_MAC", ""));

            BluetoothSocket socket = secilenYazici
                    .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


            socket.connect();// exception throwing from this line after first pring.

            OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();


// getting printable raw block from webview source.

            String[] rawBlocks = lastHTML.split("<!--RawPrint");
            String rawEnd = rawBlocks[1].split("-->")[0];
            byte[] byteArray = rawEnd.getBytes();


            stream.write(byteArray);



            stream.close();
            socket.close();
```

I think connection being lost after close but socket already creating by this code, so I think I have to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111353/android-bluetooth-printing) might help.

The matter is that your code is not complete, so it is quite hard to see where the problem comes from.

Also I think I saw somewhere that Samsung devices running on android 4.2 are having trouble with bluetooth. I don't know if it has been fixed.